# How to set the property of a Polymer component from an Angular 2 object?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, angular

I'm getting started with Angular 2 and Polymer, I got them working separately as expected, but I have trouble mixing them up. I'm trying to set the `icon` property of an `iron-icon` from the value of an Angular object. Here is my code, modified from the one in the tutorial:

TS file:

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';
@Component({ selector: 'hero-manager' })
@View({
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl: "hero/hero.tpl.html",
})
class HeroComponent {
  public hero = {"id": 1, "name": "foo", "icon": "polymer"};
}
class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  icon: string;
}

bootstrap(HeroComponent);
```

hero.tpl.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

<div><iron-icon icon="polymer"></iron-icon>{{hero.icon}}</div>
<div><iron-icon [icon]="'polymer'"></iron-icon>{{hero.icon}}</div>
<div><iron-icon icon="{{hero.icon}}"></iron-icon>{{hero.icon}}</div>
<div><iron-icon [icon]="hero.icon"></iron-icon>{{hero.icon}}</div>
```

I tried different ways to set the `polymer` value for the `icon` property. Only the first of the 4 lines work and displays the icon. In the dev tools there is no `icon` property for the 3 others. Meanwhile, `{{hero.icon}}` in the div is properly expanded to `polymer`.

What should I do to be able to dynamically set the `icon` property?

Edit: I reproduced the issue in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CkSBys?p=preview), derived from @Eric Martinez's comment.

The iron-icons import is in the template instead of being in the main html

Edit 2, after @Eric Martinez comment that says that I should be using [attr.icon]:

New questions:

- According to [iron-icon's sources](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-icon/blob/master/iron-icon.html), icon is a **property**, defined in the property object. Where is the `attr` notation coming from? Angular and Polymer have to completely different understandings of what properties should be?
- Why did it work when the import is done in index.html?

Comment: Can't reproduce, working fine for me, see this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yny0jy2YsL1se6lMpXwP?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I think I had the iron-icons import in the wrong place. I got it working thanks to your example now. Do you want to post it as answer so that I can mark the question resolved?

Comment: I wouldn't mind, but "you imported in the wrong place" it's not quite an answer. I would add too that your example is half working since it at least shows one of them, so maybe with a little bit more of investigation you could get a definitive answer and import them where you want :)

Comment: Done. I'm not quite sure where the import should go. I thought that the point of WebComponents was to have encapsulate things nicely, so if I have to import other components in the main html file (instead of in the component's view file, as I tried initially), it seems to defeat the purpose.

Comment: I want to apologize... I totally forgot about this :(. `icon` is not a property of `iron-icon` but an attribute. Angular2 by default binds to properties, but in this case you should specify `[attr.icon]`. See the [plnkr updated](http://plnkr.co/edit/13BVfPP6g9vHsqiZBUOB?p=preview). Sorry if I mislead you.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the update. I got new questions then. Edited my answer.